# Fetch data sequentially using union operator

Tags: sql, oracle, union

I am fetching data using Union operator. I want my output to be in the same order as my select queries are fetching but instead Union sorts it in alphabetical order. Can you suggest me a way to avoid getting it sorted by default.

Comment: Maybe UNION ALL can avoid the sorting. However, to be safe, you have to specify an explicit sort order. Probably possible to add an extra column for this (that contains 1,2,3 for your three parts).

Comment: Union All did the trick. Thanks buddy :)

Comment: See also http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/45005/15012 that seems to address exactly the same question.

Comment: And remember that UNION ALL will not weed out duplicates. And since 11g (I thimk) UNION will no longer sort by default.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do it in a subquery like this:

```
select * from (select x , y ,z from table1 
               UNION ALL
               select x,y,z from table2)
order by y
```

Answer (score 1):

Thilo is correct: to be safe, a query should always explicitly order the results.  Relying on implicit sorting has caused many problems in the past and will continue to cause more problems in the future.

The suggestion that `UNION ALL` will avoid the sorting is *almost* always correct.  It should work in 11g and below.  But 12c introduced [concurrent execution of union all](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/parallel003.htm#VLDBG1431), which does not guarantee the order of results any more.

Even if implicit sorting works right now it's always a good idea to add an `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 0):

You should not rely on the order if you do not specify any `ORDER BY` clause.
`UNION` guaranties uniquines of the result. Pre 10g versions used sort to remove duplicates. Newer Oracle version also might (but not must) use a hash-table to remove duplicates - therefore the result is not necessarily sorted.

`UNION ALL` does not care about uniquines.

You can simply type:

```
select x , y ,z from table1 
UNION ALL
select x,y,z from table2
order by y
```

`Order by` applies onto the whole result.